# Correct function call in php

Tags: php

```
function sendMessage ($id,$text,$keyboard_inline,$keyboard)
{
    if (isset($keyboard_inline))
     {
        $used_keyboard = '&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard":['.$keyboard_inline.']}';



     }
     else if(isset($keyboard))
     {

     }
     else
     {
        $url = $GLOBALS[$website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=$id&parsemode=HTML&text=".urlencode($text);
     }
    
    file_get_contents($url);

}
```

This is sendMessage function for telegram bots,now only one among $inline_keyboard and $keyboard are necessary ($id and $text are mandatory instead),if i have to call the function i have to call it like this:

```
sendMessage($some_id,$some_text,NULL,$some_keyboard)
```

or this:

```
sendMessage($some_id,$some_text,$some_keyboard) //here $inline_keyboard is omitted.
```

Keyboards markups are the same in both types just their appeance and handling is different.
The function is incomplete just to understand how to handle it correctly.

English is not my first language so pardon any mispell

Comment: If the function is defined with 4 parameters *required* (as you are showing), then you must call it with 4 parameters. Passing only 3 will fatal out.

Comment: so the correct one is :     
sendMessage($some_id,$some_text,NULL,$some_keyboard)

Comment: The correct one is the obvious one by process of elimination :D

Comment: ty Very very stryzzy

Comment: Chances are good, you will be able to [omit optional parameters](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) in php8. But for now you may want to have a look at default values.